# How to redirect pdf files to corresponding page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have pdf urls for each of my pages.

For example :

https://seorooz.net/panda-algorithm/?print=pdf

https://seorooz.net/panda-algorithm/

I want 301 redirect all request from pdf urls to original page urls.

How can i do this from .htaccess file?

Update:Solved.I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I  just added this code after RewriteBase / :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]+)\?print=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

And work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]+)\?print=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have some code in .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
When i added your codes in first, 404 raised for all pages.when i added to end of this codes, not work.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo that is fixed. Place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line.